# Vga 666 dual display with HDMI

Tags: raspbian

I bought the vga666 adapter with the idea of working with my raspberry using the dual display function .

I have set as indicated in the manual available on github : https://github.com/fenlogic/vga666

But does not the dual display. When configuring the file config.txt . The video output vga but not by the hdmi .

Using the program omxplayer. I can send a video signal by hdmi.

I want to know if it is possible to use dual display with rdesktop . Because in my company we want to change thin client by raspberry.

Do you know something about it?